# PostgreSQL GROUP BY issue

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

Suppose I have the table

```
      id      |       name       | number  |                address
--------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------------
 1            | channel A        |      0  | http://stream01
 2            | channel B        |      2  | http://stream02
 3            | channel C        |      16 | http://stream03
 4            | channel B        |      2  | http://stream04
 5            | channel B        |      16 | http://stream05
 6            | channel C        |      16 | http://stream06
 7            | channel A        |      7  | http://stream07
 8            | channel A        |      5  | http://stream08
 9            | channel A        |      0  | http://stream09
...etc
```

I want to remove duplicate channels (rows with the same name and number).  But I want the result to contain the other columns along with name and number.

The problem is which `id` and `address` I choose once I've removed the duplicates.  I'm happy to choose the first it finds.  So, for example, the result from the above table should be

```
      id      |       name       | number  |                address
--------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------------
 1            | channel A        |      0  | http://stream01
 2            | channel B        |      2  | http://stream02
 3            | channel C        |      16 | http://stream03
 5            | channel B        |      16 | http://stream05
 7            | channel A        |      7  | http://stream07
 8            | channel A        |      5  | http://stream08
...etc
```

I realise I'll probably need a `SELECT name,number FROM table GROUP BY name,number` in my query and the query should start off `SELECT id,name,number,address FROM (..)` but I just can't think of a way to do this in one query.

Any ideas?

Comment: With "remove" you mean you want to delete the rows or just not have them in the result?

Comment: Not have them in the result.  Have a feeling I almost have it - `SELECT id,name,number,address FROM table AS t JOIN (SELECT name,number FROM table GROUP BY name,number) AS j USING(name,number)`. Didn't quite work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name,number)
       id,
       name,
       number,
       address
  FROM table
 ORDER BY name,number,id;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried `DISTINCT ON` earlier today but it didn't work.  That's because my actual query has an `ORDER BY` at the end and was throwing the error `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`.  I can fix this by wrapping the entire query in `()` and prep-end a `SELECT * FROM` and stick my `ORDER BY` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(id),
       name,
       number,
       min(address)
FROM the_table
GROUP BY name, number;
```

**Edit:**
If you need matching id and address, then the following is another solution:

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       number, 
       address
FROM ( 
  SELECT id,
         name,
         number,
         address, 
         row_number() over (partition by name, number order by id) as rn
  FROM the_table
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: If min(id) and min(address) aren't in the same row, this will have the effect of manufacturing a row that isn't in the original table, won't it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I understood the question such that tbh1 does not care which value is returned.

Comment: Thanks for this.  My actual query is a fair bit more involved than the dumbed down one in the question. Wrapping everything in `min()` doesn't strike me as the best solution in my case, but thanks.

Comment: @tbh1: the version with the windowing function might be more flexible then.

Answer (score 0):

That should be enough:

```
 SELECT MIN(id), name, number, address FROM table GROUP BY name, number
```

Comment: Will throw an error. You need to either apply an aggregate function on address or include it in the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

I think the most understandable way to do this is with views or common table expressions. I'll use common table expressions.

```
create table test (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(20) not null,
  number integer not null,
  address varchar(30) not null
);

insert into test values 
(1, 'channel A', 0, 'http://stream01'),
(2, 'channel B', 2,   'http://stream02'),
(3, 'channel C', 16,  'http://stream03'),
(4, 'channel B', 2,   'http://stream04'),
(5, 'channel B', 16,  'http://stream05'),
(6, 'channel C', 16, 'http://stream06'),
(7, 'channel A', 7, 'http://stream07'),
(8, 'channel A', 5, 'http://stream08'),
(9, 'channel A', 0, 'http://stream09');

with unique_name_num as (
  select distinct name, number
  from test
),
min_id as (
  select number, name, min(id) id
  from test
  group by number, name
)
select t.*
from test t
inner join unique_name_num u on u.name = t.name and u.number = t.number
inner join min_id m on m.number = t.number and m.name = t.name and m.id = t.id
order by t.name, t.number
```